# Polymer 1.0 data binding options for accessing lists

Tags: polymer, dart, polymer-1.0

In Polymer 1.0, is it possible to do:

```
{{ object in house.animals }}
```

where `house.animals` is a list? In the documentation, I found only simple examples in the binding, like `{{ animals }}`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to change the name of the iterator to "object", which can be done by setting the [`<dom-repeat>.as` property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/elements/dom-repeat#property-as) (i.e., `as="object"`).

And yes, you can bind `<dom-repeat>.items` to a subproperty of an object as long as the subproperty is an `Array`.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{house.animals}}" as="{{object}}">
  <div>Type: {{object.type}}</div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/mpbNRq?editors=1010)